# SessionID is generating a unique value on every post request

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I am trying to identify the user that is on my application via sessionId, not actual info on the user account itself. However, what I am noticing is that the sessionId changes everytime the user performs an action on the page. As shown below. My goal would be to have the same sessionID from the point they open the webpage until they close it.

```
const app = require('express')();
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const session = require('express-session');

function getDateTimestamp(){
                var today = new Date();
                var date = today.getFullYear()+'_'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'_'+today.getDate();
                return date;
            }

app.use(session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: 'whatever',
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 60*60*1000,
        sameSite: true
    }
}))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  var readStream = fs.createReadStream('index.html','utf8');
  readStream.pipe(res);
});

app.post('/:fieldName/:flag/:time/:dashboard/:identifier/:user', (req, res) => {
    console.log('POST message received', req.params);
    if (req.params && req.params.fieldName) {
        fs.appendFileSync(`./changeLog_${getDateTimestamp()}.csv`, `${req.params.fieldName},${req.params.flag},${req.params.time},${req.params.dashboard},${req.params.identifier},${req.params.user},${req.sessionID}\n`);
        return res.send('OK')
    }
    res.status(400).end()
});
```

Client Side

```
function onParameterChange (parameterChangeEvent) {
                parameterChangeEvent.getParameterAsync().then(function (param) {
                    parameterIndicator = 'Parameter'
                    const details = {
                        method: 'POST',
                        credentials: 'include'
                        //body: JSON.stringify(data),
                        //  headers: {
                        //      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        //  }
                    };
                    fetch(`url/${param.name}/${parameterIndicator}/${getDateTimestamp()}/${dashboardName}/${param.name}/${worksheetData}`, details).then((res) => {console.log(res);});
                });
            }
```

Here is my output showing a different session for the same user.
[image]

Comment: You need to follow the session cookie in the browser and see what is happening to it because that is the key to reusing the same session.  You can look at the network tab in the Chrome debugger to see exactly what cookie is being returned by the server from a given request and then see what cookie is being sent back to the server from the client on the next request.  You should also check what the value of `SESS_LIFETIME` is to make sure it's not accidentally too short.

Comment: This is kind of an educated guess, but setting `saveUninitialized` to `false` may mean that no session cookie is actually set until the session is actually first modified somehow - but here you're never actually saving anything to the session. Maybe try to set it to `true` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @IAmDranged unfortunately that didn't work, but thank you for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Just to illustrate my comment above, I actually have ran a quick test with a simple setup, and toggling `saveUninitialized` actually seems to make the difference:

```
// app.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const session = require('express-session')

// Run the file as "node app false" or "node app true" to toggle saveUninitialized.
const saveUninitialized = process.argv[2] == "true" ? true : false

app.use(session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized,
    secret: 'whatever',
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000,
        sameSite: true
    }
}))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send(req.sessionID)
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server started on http://localhost:3000')
})

// Response body
node app false
// 1st request: OTnFJD-r1MdiEc_8KNwzNES84Z0z1kp2
// 2nd request: 5UVVGng_G72Vmb5qvTdglCn9o9A4N-F6
// 3rd request: 9aGsAwnHh1p1sgINa1fMBXl-oRKcaQjM
node app true
// 1st request: StUrtHOKBFLSvl5qoFai6OQCm7TY87U-
// 2nd request: StUrtHOKBFLSvl5qoFai6OQCm7TY87U-
// 3rd request: StUrtHOKBFLSvl5qoFai6OQCm7TY87U-
```

But maybe there is more to it than that with your setup.

Comment: Because I am a beginner on this, I don't know how to pass the sessionId you generated on your code to the POST call I have that writes to a file. When I try to do it, i get an error saying 'Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client'.

Comment: The cookie is automatically set by the express-session package on the server side. You need to make sure the client sends it back to the server on subsequent requests. With the above example, this is automatically taken care of by the browser. How do you make the POST request in your scenario? Do you just submit a html form? Or do you use a http client api - like fetch or axios?

Comment: I use a fetch on the client side. I edited the question to include that portion of the code a well.

Comment: `fetch()` doesn't send cookies by default, you have to opt in by setting the `credentials: 'include'` option.

Comment: I added that to the client code and tried to output req.sessionID on the server side, but still getting unique values. Maybe I added the code incorrectly? Question was edited to reflect the updated code.

Comment: The client runs on the same origin as the server, correct? If so, I'm really not sure. If you are able to post the whole code for a complete reproducable example, I'm happy to look into it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232968/discussion-between-530529-and-iamdranged).

Comment: sent it to you via chat as recommended by Stack Overlfow.